# xAxis tag in Coldfusion 8

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfml

Is there a x-axis tag in Coldfusion 8? I was going through the below link but couldn't find it on the official Adobe docs.

```
<xAxis type="DateTime" isAbsolute="false" scaleMin="0">
<labelFormat style="DateTimePattern" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy"/>
<parseFormat style="DateTimePattern" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"/>
<dateTimeStyle minorUnit="Hour"/>
<labelStyle isMultiline="false" orientation="Vertical"/>
<titleStyle font="Arial-16-bold" isMultiline="false"/>
<groupStyle>
<format pattern="#,##0.###"/>
</groupStyle>
</xAxis>
```

Source:http://www.raymondcamden.com/forums/messages.cfm?threadid=ECB52D08-A990-DA46-5A61466378765992

Comment: The charting engine is a third party component (WebCharts3D). So it has its own, separate, documentation. Typically located `{cf_installation_root}/charting/UserGuide.pdf`

Comment: @Leigh Could you tell me the precise link for `{cf_installation_root}/charting/UserGuide.pdf` ?

Comment: There is no link. The pdf is installed on your hard drive as part of the CF installation.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked CF 9 documentation but it all talks about considering WebDesigner tool and not in a normal programming language fashion just like adobe docs.

Comment: Yeah, because it is a third party component. That means it is produced by a completely different company, with its own documentation style. Welcome to the wonderful world of development ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I believe I'll have to download it and then work on it.